# How do I convert timezone date to correct local date?

Tags: javascript

I have this date:

```
2015-05-28T23:00:00.000Z
```

I need to convert it to the local date which would be (in this format):

```
29/05/2015
```

I would expect the above formatted date to be correct based on the date string above.

How would I do this?

Thank you

Comment: think best is moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert it to Date object:

```
var dateString = '2015-05-28T23:00:00.000Z';
var date = new Date(dateString)
```

then you cant format it:

```
var formatedDate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

But you can also use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment(dateString).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: This also works, if the dmy format is not a necessity: `new Date("2015-05-28T23:00:00.000Z").toLocaleString().split(',')[0]`

Comment: `split` was to extract only the date. `toLocaleString()` gives the time also

Comment: `new Date(dateString)` fails in IE 8. :-(

Answer (score 1):

It's been well covered elsewhere that using the Date constructor to parse strings isn't a good idea. The format in the OP is consistent with ES5 and will be parsed correctly by modern browsers, but not IE 8 which still has a significant user share.

Parsing the string manually isn't difficult:

```
function isoStringToDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6]));
}
```

Then to format it:

```
function dateToDMY(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  return z(d.getDate()) + '/' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
}

console.log(dateToDMY(isoStringToDate('2015-05-28T23:00:00.000Z'))); // 29/05/2015
```

To be consistent with ES5, the parse function should check values aren't out of range but if you're confident of the correctness of the string that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies.

I've got it formatted by doing:

```
var d = new Date('2015-05-28T23:00:00.000Z');
var n = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() +1 ) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following code in script

```
  <script>
   var d = new Date("2015-05-28T23:00:00.000Z");
   var str=d.toString();
       var date = new Date(str),
    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
    day  = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var local_date=[ date.getFullYear(), mnth, day ].join("/");  //yyyy/mm/dd

 </script>
```

Hope it works.Thank you